# How to retain password for Rsync across the same script?

Tags: bash, ssh, passwords, rsync

I have written this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SSH_USER=${SSH_USER:=$USER}

for department in A B C E L M V
do
    mkdir -p ./resources/${div}

    rsync -Pruzh --copy-links \
        ${SSH_USER}@server:${department}/foo/files \
        ${SSH_USER}@server:${department}/foo/photos \
        ./resources/${department}/foo

    rsync -Pruzh \
        ${SSH_USER}@server:${department}/bar/documents \
        ./resources/${department}/bar
done
```

It works perfect except that I have to write my password 14 times which is not really practical.

I have heard of `ssh_agent` but for some reasons it does not work on my WSL.

Is there any alternative that I can use to type my password only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using openssh, then you can set up a master connection and reuse it with something like:

```
DEST="${SSH_USER}@server"

TMPL=/tmp/sshctl/"%L-%r@%h:%p"
mkdir -p /tmp/sshctl
if ! ssh -nNf -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath="${TMPL}" "${DEST}"; then
    echo "# Failed to setup SSH ControlMaster. Aborting."
    exit
fi

# ...

rsync -e "ssh -o 'ControlPath=${TMPL}'" ... "${DEST}":... ...
rsync -e "ssh -o 'ControlPath=${TMPL}'" ... "${DEST}":... ...

# ...

ssh -O exit -o ControlPath="${TMPL}" "${DEST}"
```

Be sure to secure the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to set up SSH key pairs for automated authentication; i.e. create an SSH key pair and copy the public key to the server where these files are located, then use the private key in the rsync command: `rsync -Pruzh --copy-links -e "ssh -i /path/to/private.key" ...`. This is fairly simple, secure, and gets rid of the prompt.

You can also use a utility like `sshpass` to enter the password in the prompt, but that kind of approach is less secure.